# Finding dns-sd package for FreeBSD and Linux?

Tags: linux, freebsd, free-software

IETF RFC 6763 section 7.1 ([p.21](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6763)) refers to a CLI program called "dns-sd", which can be used to probe and report zero-config services, records and environments. A number of other web pages also refer to using it in the CLI, but none give a source repo or originating web URL. I don't really want to download a large package containing it, since I only want to probe the dns servers, or to scan the reachable network and get detailed dumps of dns-sd accessible services/directories/?activity when a dns server may or may not be running, not much more, and I can't find a standalone package for it, or even its ultimate upstream source. I can't even be 100% sure what it's capable of, because I can't find its docs either. But it *sounds* like the right one.

Any ideas how to track such a thing down? And, if they exist, ports for FBSD 11.x and various flavours of Linux (can compile if there is a full Makefile+source). For once, Google hasn't been my friend. Nor has freshports, nor any other search I know.

Comment: What makes you thing that `dns-sd` is a command line tool?  You may be looking for [Avahi](https://avahi.org/).

Comment: The RFC does talk about running a command-line tool on MacOS, Kusalananda.

Comment: @JdeBP Ah, so it does. I was looking at page 22.

Comment: Avahi project also has an utility to browse mdns entries.

Comment: @arrowd - it appears to browse _entries_ (in DNS), not reported/reportable data (from polling/listening to devices). I'm looking for a bit more, and hoping this early dns-sd utility might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dns-sd` command is part of the [net/mDNSResponder](https://freshports.org/net/mDNSResponder/) port in FreeBSD.  The aforelinked FreshPorts entry shows its origin.  It is the [net/mDNSResponder](http://cdn.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/net/mDNSResponder/) package in NetBSD.

None of Debian, OpenSUSE, or Ubuntu appear to package it.

Apple's on-line manual pages for Darwin, where one would have found the `dns-sd`(1) doco, have been famously gone for years.  One can still read the raw roff source of the manual in the mDNSResponder package in Apple's OpenSource repository, if desperate, and that is what you have to compile if building from source (and is of course what is compiled in the ports).

Comment: Out of date probably isn't much of an issue - code is network facing and reports on packets in a fairly static protocol. So the protocols/calls it uses itself, won't be nearly as affected as if it was complex and related to things that change profoundly in a few years. Also sounds like perhaps not a big codebase, so maybe easy to bring up to date and compile standalone n FBSD, at least, especially if it's still maintained in some form  on FBSD and netbsd. Thank you!